# grep/awk specific lines based on specific fields; using ksh variable with awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, ksh

I have this input file: **file_in.txt** (delimited by pipe)

```
3345:tyg|rty|27|0|0|ty6|{89|io|}62|0
3346:tyg|rtyuio|63|0|1|ty6|{89|gh|}45|0
3347:tyu|ray|24|0|0|ty6|{89|uh|}27|0
3348:tyg|rtoy|93|0|1|ty6|{89|yh|}1|0
3349:tyo|rtert|28|0|0|ty6|{89|gh|}27|0
```

I want to get only those lines which have 9th field value as `}27` using `'|'` as delimiter so that my output should be:

```
3347:tyu|ray|24|0|0|ty6|{89|uh|}27|0
3349:tyo|rtert|28|0|0|ty6|{89|gh|}27|0
```

Below command works fine:

```
awk -F"|" '{ if ($9 == "}27") print $0 }' file_in.txt
```

But I want to use a shell variable instead of `"}27"` for which I tried this:

```
taskid="}27"    
awk -v tid="$taskid" -F"|" '{ if ($9 == "}tid") print $0 }' file_in.txt
```

Please help me figure out where I am going wrong with this command.
Any other command suggestions to achieve the same are appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of the command you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your shell variable $tasked has the value `27`, you want to use one of these forms:

1. build the string with the open brace in the shell

   ```
   awk -v tid="}$taskid" -F"|" '$9 == tid' file
   ```
2. or do it in awk --- awk's string concatenation is just placing strings side-by-side with optional whitespace in between

   ```
   awk -v tid="$taskid" -F"|" '$9 == "}" tid' file
   ```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
taskid="}27"

awk -F'|' -v tid="$taskid" '$9 == tid' file
```

**Output:**

```
3347:tyu|ray|24|0|0|ty6|{89|uh|}27|0
3349:tyo|rtert|28|0|0|ty6|{89|gh|}27|0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your own command should have worked with this change:

```
$ ksh
$ taskid=}27
$ awk -v tid=$taskid -F"|" '{ if ($9 == tid) print $0}' file_in.txt
```

> Output:
>   3347:tyu|ray|24|0|0|ty6|{89|uh|}27|0
>   3349:tyo|rtert|28|0|0|ty6|{89|gh|}27|0

Comment: I wqant to match `$9` to `}tid` and not to `tid`...so this doesn't work.

Comment: I am not sure what have you changed in your requirements. But there is no reason for the one I have indicated not to work. For clarity on what I want to solve based on your req, I have added few additional lines.

Comment: Now it works fine...I am getting taskid as `27` from another command and not `}27` so answer suggested by glenn seems to be more appropriate...however this edited version also works fine ..thanks